# Spotlight angular attenuation causes sharp edges when angle > 90

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

If the cone angle is over 90 degrees, my spot light's angular attenuation is not working correctly. From 0.1 to 90, the attenuation is smooth from the center of the cone to the edges, but from 90 to 179.9, it gets sharper and sharper edges.

Here's my attenuation code:

```
uniform vec3 lightPosition; // Light's position
uniform vec3 lightDirection; // Light's direction
uniform float lightAngleCos: // Cosine of the half of the cone angle
uniform float lightRange: // Light's range

// Get the light vector
vec3 pixelToLight = lightPosition - position.xyz;
vec3 normPTL = normalize(pixelToLight);    

// Get the dot product between the light direction and the light vector
float rho = dot(normPTL, -lightDirection);

if(rho > lightAngleCos)
{
    float dif = 1.0 - lightAngleCos;
    float angularAttenuation = clamp((rho - lightAngleCos) / dif, 0.0, 1.0);
    float radialAttenuation = 1.0 - clamp(length(pixelToLight) / (lightRange), 0.0, 1.0);
    float attenuation = angularAttenuation * radialAttenuation;

    // Apply attenuation
    out_color = color * attenuation;
}
```

Comment: In which direction is your `lightDirection` pointing, from the light or to the light (from your computation it seems *to* the light, but this would be strange, so just to be sure)?

Comment: It's the actual direction of the light, but I seem to have written the pixelToLight wrong. Going to fix that.

Comment: *"but I seem to have written the pixelToLight wrong"* - Wrong in your question or wrong in your actual code. In the latter case this may very well be the answer to your question.

Comment: It was wrong in the question, I didn't copy-paste the original code but wrote it instead, so I included a mistake there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original solution was correct altogether. It was my cone mesh that caused limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Calc it in actual angles, not in cos, since cos is not linear, so you had very smooth attenuation gradient near 0, and very sharp near 180, you can see that just by looking at cos graph near 0 and near Pi/2.

In code you should calc:

```
rhoAngle = acos(rho);
lightAngleCos = acos(lightAngleCos);
```

and then use it to calc attenuation:

```
float dif = Pi/2.0 - lightAngle;
float angularAttenuation = clamp((lightAngle - rhoAngle) / dif, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, give me an example?

Comment: your example does not work, it produces no lighting at all. AngularAttenuation is zero in all cases.

Comment: @manabreak how did you test it? I wrote arccos instead of acos, so it should not even compile, fixed the answer to correct naming of arccosinus, also Pi constand should be defined.

Comment: I did all the necessary changes, but it didn't work. I guess it's because you subtract lightAngle from rhoAngle, while it should be vice versa. Anyhow, my original solution was correct in the first place, the sharp edge was actually caused by my cone mesh.

Comment: @manabreak I just rewrote what was written in your code. Anyway statement stays true with sin of angle you get sharper edges then with angle, fixed answer to make it correct.